# Doctrine fetching objects creates memory exhaustion at about 4000 objects

Tags: memory, doctrine

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted.

There are a few cases where I need to create 10's of thousands of results, but obviously this is causing huge memory issues. Are there any ways of reducing the memory on large query sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you will use the results:

- if you don't need the result as object but array will suffice you
  can change hydration mode:
  `->setHydrationMode(Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY)` can be used to retrieve
  data in a multidimensional array (other hydration mode can be found
  on [doctrine documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/data-hydrators/en))
- if you need objects as result (for example in a foreach cycle) remember to free them after use: 
  `$myobject->free(); /* if using php 5.2 also unset($myobject) */`
  look also at doctrine [docs on performance improving](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/improving-performance/en#free-objects)
- also disabling debug bar helps a lot on big doctrine collections: `sfConfig::set('sf_debug', false);`